# How do I make a custom editor in visual studio 15 RC?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to make a Visual Studio extension with a custom editor in VS 15 RC and I've followed the [MSDN tutorials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166460(v=vs.140).aspx), but the VSPackage option does not show under extensibility. Does anyone know what I'm missing or a workaround for this?

Update: This appears - from what I've heard from on MSDN - to be a issue with the VS 15 RC SDK. Here is a link to the [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/1336400/vspackage-option-does-not-show-under-extensibilty) please vote.

Comment: This feature is available in VS 13 but not in VS 15 RC, anyone know what else I can do?

Answer (score -1):

1. You need [Visual Studio SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286983.aspx) to build your own extension.
2. You can have your own extension designated to your preferred VS editor by clicking right button and `Open With...->` on Visual Studio Solution Explorer.

   If you wish to have a different text editor beside VS ones, then do the same on the Windows Explorer.

**EDIT:**

Since Ron Beyer claims that the link I provided is inappropriate because of the
version difference(my intended purpose was a link to the latest page that describes it though),
here is the page where you can download `Visual Studio 2015 RC SDK`.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx

Comment: The SDK you posted is for VS2013 and the Windows File association doesn't say what editor to use in VS for a particular type of file.

Comment: @RonBeyer The link to Visual Studio SDK that I provided is not for giving the OP Visual Studio SDK itself, but introducing what Visual Studio SDK is about. Since Visual Studio 2015 is still 'Release Candidate', that's , I assume, the latest page describing it. If you can help me finding an official introducing MSDN page to Visual Studio 2015 RC, then I'm willing to elaborate my answer.

Comment: @RonBeyer By 'What editor to use in VS', The OP didn't mention editor IN VISUAL STUDIO(just, a default editor), but also Visual Studio does not provide numbers of editor. Visual Studio has a Visual Studio editor.

Comment: The site is about programming and the question is about VS. VS has a large number of editors in it, for example, the code editor, JSON editor, HTML, XML, CSS, LESS, Binary, Resource, XAML, Winforms, Hex, etc. You can set editors for files by right clicking on them in Solution Explorer and choosing "Open With", and is the same regardless of the version of Windows (in VS).

Comment: @RonBeyer Fair enough. 
However the 'bonus' question could be literally a bonus, which I assumed as a VS-irrelevant question, asking about choosing an editor other than Visual Studio, such as SubLime/Notepad++/etc, 
because you barely need something like opening your C++ plain source files with the VS binary editor.
You can't deny that the OP's question is quite vague about that.

Comment: @RonBeyer Furthermore, except for the binary editor, other editors you mentioned are just the same editor with different syntax highlighting functions.
It's like you can NOT say that Sublime has a large number of editors such as HTML Sublime editor, JSON Sublime editor, and C++ Sublime editor. You just say 'Sublime editor'.

Comment: @RonBeyer Finally, I believe that the answer about Visual Studio SDK for his 'non-bonus' question is still valid.

Comment: Can we discuss this here? :-) 
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77822/discussion-room-to-q

Comment: Do you know a work around for creating a custom editor cause I repaired VS 15 RC SDK and it didn't change anything.

Comment: @chabad360 When the SDK is officially supported for that, you do not need to find a work around beside using the SDK. Visual Studio SDK you installed should provide you with options for what you're looking for. Otherwise you're missing something else on some unknown part. Please describe specifically how it is not working.

Comment: You can check my post, but to say it again, The VSPackage option (or the Visual Studio Package template in MSDN tutorials), is not shown under extensibility, and I cannot make custom editors because of this...